# VueTailwind apply nextPage in fetchOptions in TRichSelect?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css, ui-select2

I've been looking for hours in their documentation [here](https://www.vue-tailwind.com/docs/rich-select/) on how to pass the `nextPage` in the `fetchOption` prop, it seems that the documentation is incomplete. anyone tried using this feature?

Appriciate the answers. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the [repo](https://github.com/alfonsobries/vue-tailwind/), i found out that the `fetchOptions` should return `hasMorePages` attribute to trigger the pagination in the component.